# How to use max value attribute using angularjs uib-progressbar?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, progress-bar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to set max value to 200 count and when i receive message it should show current messages count in progressbar , With below code when i send one message whole progress bar display 100% and it also shows text in the progressbar. Any idea ?

main.html

```
<uib-progress><uib-bar ng-repeat="bar in event track by $index" max="max" value="bar"><span ng-hide="bar < 5">{{bar}}%</span></uib-bar></uib-progress>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.max = 200;
$scope.event = ["lorem ipsum","lorem ipsum","lorem ipsum"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this max="{{max}}"

```
<uib-progress><uib-bar ng-repeat="bar in event track by $index" max="{{max}}" value="bar"><span ng-hide="bar < 5">{{bar}}%</span></uib-bar></uib-progress>
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution did not work, It also shows text inside progressbar not sure why.

Comment: it worked if i removed ng-repeat and set different configuaration, Thanks